# Передача значения в FirstViewContr из SecondViewContr

Tags: xcode, iphone

Доброго времени суток,
Прошу сильно не ругать если что-то скажу не правильно, так как только начинаю работать с xcode.
Проблема в следующем:

Есть первое представление `firstViewController`, в его `.h` файле:

```
+(NSInteger)getSum;
```

В его `.m` файле:

```
static int sumForSecView;

+(NSInteger)getSum {
    return sumForSecView;
}
```

в самом `.m` файле в одной из функций для `sumForSecView` присваивается значение.

В сторибоарде создан `SecondViewController`, сделана связь из кнопки `firstViewController`-а в `SecondViewController` в режиме `modal`.

В `.m` файле `SecondViewController`-а идет присвоение:

```
_newSum = [firstViewController getSum];
```

Все работает правильно.

Далее в `SecondViewController`-е, с переменной `_newSum` производятся некие арифметические действия с участием пользователя, вследтвие чего она принимает новое значение.

Задача: Вернуть новое(вычесленное) значение переменной `_newSum` из `secondViewController`-а, в переменную `SumForSecView` `firstViewController`-а, или присвоить ее значение другой переменной `firstViewController`-а по нажатию кнопки и передать управление `firstViewController`-у

Как я пробовал: Сделал связь кнопки `SeconViewController`-а с `firstViewController`-ом в режиме modal

Результат: по нажатию кнопки `Second`-а, управление передается `First`-у, а как передать вычисленное значение не знаю.

Спасибо за ответы. Буду признателен если будет немного поподробнее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

все просто

- добавляем в SecondViewController.h

  @property (nonatomic, copy) void (^didFinishHandler)(int sum);
- называем в сториборде segue ("SecondVC")
- в первом котроллере добавляем метод

  ```
  - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegur *)segue sender:(id)sender
  {
        /* одна важная вещь для правильного memory management при использовании блоков */
        __weak FirstViewController *self_ = self; // создаем слабую сслыку на себя же, используем внутри блока только ее
        if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondVC"]) {
            SecondViewController *vc = segue.destinationViewController;
            vc.didFinishHandler = ^(int sum){
                 /* тут добавляем свою обработку нового значение  и делаем */
                 [self_.navigationController popViewControlelrAnimated:YES];
            };
        }
  }
  ```
- в secondVC добавляем в нужный момент вызов блока
- (void)calculationEnds
         {
                      if (self.didFinishHandler) {
                          self.didFinishHandler(self.newSum);
                      }
                 }

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, пробовал разными путями,но5
По нажатию кнопки Close SVC (к которой привязан модальный SecondVC), я вставил блок if (self.didFinishHandler) { self.didFinishHandler(self.newSum); } , как вы и посоветовали, но при пошаговом дебаге это условие (if (self.didFinishHandler) не выполняется, т.е. false похоже.
Просто SVC закрывается и открывается FVC, причем в FVC не проходит через метод prepareForSegue.
Т.е. вот это if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SecondVC"])... условие даже не проверяется при возврате от SVC к FVC

Comment: Все спасибо огромное. Я разобрался, не тот сегвей назвал SecondVC. Надо было исходный, а я назвал второй  – который на закрытие. Начал логичеки смотреть и понял что не правильно сделал.